# IIS redirect rules

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-7

I can't redirect all request to one page. I used a lot of examples, but they don't work for me.
My last rule:

```
<rule name="redirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="exemple" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.exemple.org/en/abex" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

I need to redirect all pages in the site to https://www.example.org/en/abex. But I have a loop maybe because this page redirects too? or not?
I don`t know. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create negative match condition, which is excluding `https://www.example.org/en/abex` url from the rule:

```
<rule name="redirect" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^en/abex$" negate="true" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.exemple.org/en/abex" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```